# Javascript image slider doesn't work with external *.js file

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, slider

I've been busting my mouse and keyboard the last 2 days to build a functional image slider/carousel for my website using some code that I've seen somewhere else. I've tried to adapt it my needs and end up splitting it into external HTML/CSS and JS files as inline javascript/CSS is a nono.

The code has 2 parts, 1st half adds the forward and back buttons, the 2nd part builds the timeout slider.

If I split the code into 3 files it throws me this error, every single time.

```
slider.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at showImage (slider.js:19)
    at slider.js:8
```

when it reaches

```
x[index-1].style.display = "block";
```

**Using inline javascript works just fine.** But I must use external files.

[image]

```
var index = 1;

function plusIndex(n){
    index = index + 1;
    showImage(index);
}

showImage(1);

function showImage(n){
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
    if(n > x.length){ index = 1};
    if(n < 1){ index = x.length};
    for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    x[index-1].style.display = "block";
}
autoSlide();
function autoSlide(){
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
    for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    index++;
    if(index > x.length){index = 1}
    x[index-1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(autoSlide,2000);

}
```

Comment: Have you tried doing `console.log(x)` and `console.log(index - 1)` to see what you're actually working with?

Comment: @Ani what's wrong with OP's tone?

Comment: Sorry for the language, it was addressed to myself.

Comment: @JackTrade don't sweat it. It isn't necessary, but certainly isn't something to call you out over. Your tone seems fine to me.

Comment: It's weird, if I run the code in the console (chrome), the slider works, better said the images are starting switching.  console.log(x) gives me this: "VM96:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13"

Comment: I've figured it out. I put the <script type="text/javascript" src="js/slider.js"></script> just at the end of the html file. It works. :) Thank you.